# Telerik RadButton with JQuery

Tags: jquery, telerik

I am trying to do something fairly simple with a RadButton and JQuery.  I have a repeater with divs, a radbutton, and an inner div that should .slideDown or .slideUp (inner_container) using JQuery when the button is clicked.  I need this to only happen for the div inner_container within the outside_container of the button that was clicked.

Being in a repeater these buttons and styles are repeated so I need a specific container otherwise they all open and close.  I cannot get the .parents("outside_container").find("inner_container").slideDown() to work because I cant seem to find specific radbutton id or if I do using var button = sender.get_id(); the jquery functions .parents() don't work with it?

I am at a loss on how to get this slide up and down to work with RadButtons.  And I am not able to switch to asp:buttons because this is an existing project that I am updating.

```
function ShowVoidDetail(sender, args) 
{
   var button = sender.get_id();

    $(button).parents(".event_is_void_container").find(".event_is_void").slideDown();
    sender.set_text("Hide Void Event");

    args.set_cancel(true);
 }
```

aspx page below...

```
<asp:repeater>
<itemtemplate>
        <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
                     <div class="event_is_void_container">
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <rad:RadButton id="btnShowDetails" OnClientClicking="ShowDetail"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="event_is_void"> /*this style is display:none by default*/
                        A bunch of data...
                    </div>
                <div>
            </td>
        </tr>
</itemtemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a class to your button then you could bind the click event to that class and then use the `this` element to action only the button that was clicked, like this

```
$('.expandButton').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
});
```

And your repeater code would look something like this:

```
   <asp:repeater>
   <itemtemplate>
           <table>
       <tr>
           <td>
                        <div class="event_is_void_container">
                       <div class="buttons">
                           <rad:RadButton id="btnShowDetails" 
                          OnClientClicking="ShowDetail" class="expandButton" />   
                       </div>

                       <div class="event_is_void"> /*this style is display:none by default*/
                           A bunch of data...
                       </div>
                   <div>
               </td>
           </tr>
   </itemtemplate>
```

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/Z5s95/

Comment: I also just found out that if I add a # to the id that I am capturing with sender.get_id() than that works in my $(button).parents... call.

problem solved